# How to have both public access and private access in AWS s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have an `s3 bucket` that has two keys (folders or I don't know how these should be called): `public` and `private`. The public key should be accessible by everybody since only things there are avatars and some guidance documents. Now in the private directory I have sensitive documents that should only be accessible by `signed URLs` generated by my `PHP API`.

I have created a `Cloudfront` distribution and behavior.

Origin Domain Name = myproject-development.s3.amazonaws.com

Path Pattern is `Default (*)`

And I cannot for the love of god figure out the policy: currently everything is accessible by public and I know this is because of the statement `Sid 2`

My current policy for the bucket:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myproject-development/public/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:ExistingObjectTag/public": "yes"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::myproject-development/private/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::myproject-development/private"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

My bucket settings has `Block all public access` on (everything is green).

If I remove the Sid 2 then everything in the private is hidden but it doesn't even work with the signed url, access is always denied!

How do I need to modify my policy so that the `/private` content is only allowed with signed url?

Comment: You don't need Sid 2. signed url permissions depend on permissions of your instance role I guess. Does the instance role have s3 permissions?

Comment: @Marcin Do you mean the IAM user role? The role has permissions to generate signed URLs. But I want to create signed url trough cloudfront and share it with my cloudfront url not by my s3 bucket ARN

Comment: Oh I see. I got confused with s3 pre-signed urls.

Comment: I think the easiest/cleanest solution is to simply use 2 S3 buckets and add them as origins behind your CF distribution. If that is not an option you can always fully lockdown your S3 bucket and add 2 CF behaviors (one restricted and the other one public). If you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Turns out it needs to be done with `CloudFront origin behavior`.

I created a new origin for path `/private` and after creating the `cache behavior` for it I added this clause shown here:

[image]

This way I was able to block public access to the folder.